# Pass LPWSTR to C#

Tags: c++-cli

I'm working on a 'C++' project, that involves printing.
To simplify some operations, I've written a piece of code in 'C#', and I have created a dll. One of the methods in 'C#' code has this signature:

`public bool PrintPDF(String printer, String sheetFormat, String path, int copies)`

Then I've imported it in 'C++' this way:

`#using <MyDll.dll>`

I'm trying to pass `LPWSTR` to this method from 'C++' native code, but even if I read many posts and docs, I cannot achieve this.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What is your code? What's the error?

Comment: C++ or managed C++?

Comment: You need a type that is supported in both languages.  I would suggest `char *`.

Comment: .net & c++ types https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0wf2yk2k.aspx

Comment: @stark - given that `System.Char` is a 16-bit data type, I would have expected `wchar_t*` (which is what `LPWSTR` is typedef'ed to) to be at least as well as supported as `char*`.

Comment: To expand on Gusman's question:  Are you prepared to use Microsoft's extension to C++ called "managed C++" which allows direct access to .Net types and methods?

Comment: D'oh!  You are using `#using` so you are *already* using Managed C++.

Comment: Use `gcnew String(var)` where var is your lpcwstr variable.

Comment: @Gusman - I'm using C++ / CLI (I started a new CLR project in visual studio)

Comment: @Martin Bonner - I'm not prepared to use Managed C++. I searched a lot in internet but the result was a lot of confusion.

Comment: @HansPassant : Bother - your tag edit removed my Mjolnir.  (I think it was correct though.)

Comment: @MatteoMeil C++ / CLI is managed C++.